# Name-related string manipulation in Python

Tags: python

I have a set of strings like "LastName, FirstName". I want to return them as "FirstName%LastName". How would I do this?

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Have you tried `name = name.replace(", ", "%")`? Simple string replacement of whatever separates LastName and FirstName?

Comment: `'%'.join(s.split(', '))`

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh, good try, but I am looking for FirstName%LastName. Your example returns LastName%FirstName.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, you made the same mistake that Devesh did.

Comment: No one noticed the swapping of names. :P

Comment: `'%'.join(reversed(s.split(', '))`?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh, I provided an example in the question. In case you didn't read it the first time, I have a string "LastName, FirstName". I want it to be returned as "FirstName%LastName".

Comment: ```s.split(', ')[1]+'%'+s.split(', ')[0]```

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy, nice correction! Your solution works, good job. Not sure why this question was so downvoted.

Comment: You are correct, in that case `'%'.join(s.split(', ')[::-1])` should work also your question doesn't provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) hence the downvotes

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible solution.

```
final_result = '%'.join(reversed(playername.split(', ')))
```